# How to add meta-characters to a regEx expression when using a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

As you can see from the example, I passed a variable called snoop to coincide for the word argument in the function. I want whatever value I put in for word to be put under the same type of meta-characters. The problem is that every time I try to put meta-charaters around word ie. (
var snoop = new RegExp( /\bword/, 'gi' )) for example, it doesn't work. What would be the proper way to code this?

```
var gill = ['airplane','airport','apple','ball']

function auto (word, array){
    var geo = array.join(" ")

    var snoop = new RegExp(word, 'gi' )

    var gip = geo.match(snoop)

    console.log(gip)

}

auto("ai", gill)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "meta-characters"? `var snoop = new RegExp( "\b" +  word, "gi" )`?

Comment: These [],^,$,* etc...

Comment: Use string version of `RegExp`; e.g., `new RegExp("^" + word)`

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain why I would have to  use double backslashes with the metacharacter "\b"?    for example...                                            var snoop = new RegExp("\\b" + word, "gi")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "word" in `new RegExp( /\bword/, 'gi' ))` is just the literal string "word".  It's not a reference to your *variable* `word`.  You can create a new `RegExp` object using a string, which may be built up using concatenation.

Keep in mind that you'll need to use double backslashes, because a single backslash in a string literal begins an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).  For example `"\b"` is the backspace character.  The special escape sequence `"\\"` produces a backlash, which is what you want in your regular expression.

Here is an example that produces what I think you were trying to achieve:

```
var snoop = new RegExp("\\b" + word, "gi")
```

You can use this technique to interpolate a variable into any portion of a regular expression:

```
// Capture one or more of the characters in `validCharacters` after an equals-sign.
new RegExp("=([" + validCharacters + "]+)")
```

Comment: Can you please go deeper into why im using double slashes? I would also like to learn the general format for this so I can be free to add as many meta-characters as id like wwhat if it wanted to do this : /new RegExp(\b\w^[word]$/) for example. What would be the syntax?

Comment: so this double backslash goes for \B,\w,\s as well?  Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Yep!  The double-backslash is actually just to _produce a backslash_.